# Check if a string is all alphanumeric with regular expressions in C programming

Tags: c, regex, alphanumeric

I want to check whether a string only contains alphanumeric characters or not in C. I do not want to use the `isalnum` function. Why doesn't the code below work correctly?

```
int main()
{
    printf("test regular expression\n");
    int retval = 0;
    regex_t re;
    char line[8] = "4a.zCCb";
    char msgbuf[100];
    if (regcomp(&re,"[a-zA-z0-9]{2,8}", REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile regex '%s'\n", tofind);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ((retval = regexec(&re, line, 0, NULL, 0)) == 0)
        printf("Match : %s\n", line);
    else  if (retval == REG_NOMATCH)
        printf("does not match : %s\n", line);
    else {
        regerror(retval, &re, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }
    regfree(&re);
}
```

Comment: @KarthikT: The code includes the sample input.  Granted, it doesn't express the actual output (which is 'Match') compared with the expected output (which is 'does not match').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the entire string to be alphanumeric, you need to include begin and end anchors in the regex:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,8}$"
```

As it stands, there are 4 alphanumerics at the end of the string, which matches the original regex.

Comment: +1, deleted mine as for some reason I read `C#`... Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. it should be  `a-zA-Z`?

Comment: @jian: Why?  The word "alphanumeric" used in the questions means "letters and numbers", and the regex shown uses `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (the same as my answer).  I could have used `[[:alnum:]]` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as it means the same thing, but I followed the OP's notation so the answer was familiar to them (whereas `[[:alnum:]]` and its relatives are probably not, though they're rather useful).

Comment: my mistake. I mean it should be `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,8}$"? even "^[a-zA-z0-9]{2,8}$" still works.

Comment: I see I have `A-z` where I should have `A-Z` — you're right about that.  Thanks!  The notation with A-z 'works' but picks up the punctuation after `Z` and before `a` — namely ```[\]^_` ``` (assuming a code set based on ISO 8859 or ASCII, which includes UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Try using \w* to match all word characters.

Comment: That will match zero or more characters, which is hardly 'all alphanumeric'.